# Read Body multiple times in ASP.Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

I need to be able to read the body of the request for logging purposes early in a pipeline but I am unable to rewind it back.

Sample code here (thanks to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/re-reading-asp-net-core-request-bodies-with-enablebuffering/):

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();

    // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(
        context.Request.Body,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
        detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
        bufferSize: bufferSize,
        leaveOpen: true))
    {
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        // Do some processing with body…

        // Reset the request body stream position so the next middleware can read it
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0; <<---- throws exception
    }

    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
    await next(context);
}
```

this throws the following exception when rewinding:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
>   Object name: 'Collection'.'

Answer (score 1):

You will need to copy the body data in a new stream and put it back in the body:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(
        context.Request.Body,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
        detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
        bufferSize: bufferSize,
        leaveOpen: true))
{
    var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    // Do some processing with body

    // Get the body data    
    byte[] bodyData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

    // Put a new stream with that data in the body
    context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(bodyData);
}

// Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
await next(context);
```

Comment: This still throws the same exception @ context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(bodyData);

Comment: I found where the problem was, in my original code I've had an async serialization operation before I was writing the body back into the context. This apparently allowed the code run further into the next middleware(MVC in my case) and that middleware disposed it, so by the time the async was finished it was already gone.